# Docker compose command where it is looking for?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to use the command option in a docker-compose file to overwrite the CMD option in a dockerFile. But it's not working, I don't know where the docker is looking... I tried to put my file everywhere :
- in the container (/usr/bin/)
- with my docker-compose
- in my host (/usr/bin/)

I always get the same error :

```
Cannot start service app: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \"wait-for-maria.sh\": executable file not found in $PATH"
```

You can find below my docker-compose

```
  app:
    volumes:
        - ./code:/var/www/html/
    depends_on:
        - db
    command: ["wait-for-maria.sh","fpm_start.sh"]
```

I tried `command: ["./wait-for-maria.sh","fpm_start.sh"]` not working either

Where I have to put my file?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the complete path for both scripts, or use the [WORKDIR](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir) directive in your Dockerfile. The executable bit must be set for the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I think it searches the container itself, which resides in RAM and is accessible only through docker. You can define dockerfile instruction file in the docker-compose.yml (dockerfile: /path_to_your_dockerfile/MyDockerFile) and there run a command: "COPY your_relative_actual_path/wait-for-maria.sh destination_path_within_the_container_from_root/wait-for-maria.sh" to copy the file into the container

You can command it to run then from the dockerfile as well by: RUN path_to_sh_file

When the container starts you should be able to find it in the container by typing: "docker exec -ti your_container_name bash" in the terminal and then searching for it